# Что делать с рекламой в сообщениях?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, правила, спам

Что делать если в вопросе или ответе содержится ссылка на сайт, который отношения к вопросу/ответу не имеет? Сегодня встретил ответ, содержание которого было примерно следующим:

> "Бла бла бла"

какой-то текст, с кодом, который похож на ответ.
Потом:

> "если помогло, заходи ко мне на сайт[ссылка] и оставляй комментарии"

вот эту часть я удалил, т.к. не вижу, каким образом она отвечает на вопрос.

Правил на этот счёт я не видел, так что хотелось бы узнать правильно ли я поступил и что делать в таких ситуациях в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Очень важно отмечать такие сообщения как "Спам". Если таких пользователей наберётся шесть человек (вроде), то даже вмешательство модератора не понадобится, и сообщение будет уничтожено. Более того, оно даже после удаления сохранит отмеченное как спам состояние, и его текст можно будет увидеть, только нажав по ссылке списка правок.

Ну и можно было заметить, что спамер не написал собственный ответ, а криво скопипастил уже существующий с неверной припиской. Исправлять такое смысла мало, если по ссылке не находится что-то вредительское. Если оставить спам в изначальном состоянии, то больше вероятность, что он будет быстро удалён в отсутствие модератора.

Answer (score 5):

@ixSci, помимо этого необходимо отмечать подобные сообщения тревогой, обращая на них внимание модератора.
По поводу правил, вот выдержка из [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

> **Spam**, personal attacks, and abusive language do not have a place on
>   the Stack Exchange Network.

Answer (score -3):

вопрос про рекламу, не про пиар? я вот вижу вопрос и точно знаю что у меня в бложике та же задача расписана от и до. почему я не могу скинуть ссыль на свой блог?

Comment: Реклама и пиар(PR) это одно и то же. Но то. о чём Вы говорите отличается, от того. о чём говорил я. В том посте, что я видел была ссылка на ресурс, который к вопросу отношения не имел. Если у Вас в блоге есть полностью расписанный ответ, то Вы можете оставить ссылку на него в комментарии. Или привести ответ(можно частично), который будет отвечать на вопрос и дальше оставить ссылку на блог, мол, в блоге расписано подробнее. Просто ответ-ссылка на блог не принимается и должен быть удалён.

Comment: Потому что SO - это база накопления знаний. Если завтра вы забудете проплатить хостинг, ваш бложик станет недоступен и знания будут утрачены. По этой же причине удаляются ссылки на "учебные видео" на YouTube.