# Спам не [требует-правки], спам требует немедленного удаления!

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги, спам

Только что наблюдал, как совершенно очевидный спам закрывали как [требует правки] c кастомной причиной:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Спам не требует правки!** Пять человек потратили свои тревоги мимо. В такой ситуации нужно:

1. Сразу отметить <kbd>тревога</kbd> — <kbd>спам</kbd>. [Для удаления спама достаточно отметок тревоги от шести участников](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (или одного модератора):

   > The system will automatically delete any post flagged **six times** as offensive or spam.
2. Проголосовать против сообщения. (Не жалейте репутации на минусы ответам, она вернется, когда ответ будет удален).

---

Раньше здесь была рекомендация поменять текст сообщения на "здесь был спам", но я больше не рекомендую так делать. **Текст не нужно менять**, т.к. если вы ошибётесь в распознавании спама, у других проверяющих не будет шанса исправить вашу ошибку. Другими словами, заменяя текст сообщения на "это спам, удаляйте его", вы берёте на себя всю ответственность, которая в норме разделяется между шестью участниками.

К тому же, удалённые как спам сообщения используются в качестве материала для аудита в очереди проверок. Если там написано "привет, я аудит; нажми кнопку тревоги", то это плохой аудит.

Когда сообщение удаляется, система сама [заменяет текст на шаблонный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3909/181472).

Связанный вопрос: [Что делать с рекламой в сообщениях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337/181472)