# Снова спам не обрабатывается как спам

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги, спам

Продолжение этой истории: [Спам не [требует-правки], спам требует немедленного удаления!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/972/181472)

Вчера наткнулся на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470487/181472) в очереди новых сообщений. Очевидно, что это спам. Запостил его в чат.

Два момента, которые меня обеспокоили:

1. Судя по комментарию под удаленным ответом, он попадал в очередь VLQ (откуда его и удалили). Ему там не место, на таком ответе нужно сразу жать «тревога» — «спам».

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Простое удаление не несет таких последствий для автора, как удаление через «спам». А в данном случае это явно спам-аккаунт и он подлежит немедленному бану.
2. В чате [мне возразили](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=25765395#25765395), что теперь сообщать о спаме можно только в каком-то особом чате.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Нет! Основной чат использовался и будет использоваться для того, чтобы в срочном порядке модерировать особо злостные нарушения, такие как спам и оскорбления.

---

#### Update.

Просматривая ленту новых ответов на старые вопросы, обнаружил целых 5 спам-ответов от одного пользователя, проживших на сайте с 19 ноября (сегодня 30е).

Давайте не будем просить спамеров уточнять их спам? Ну очевидно же!

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы видите спам в очереди, то имеет смысл *первым движением* открыть пост в отдельном окне, **отметить его как спам**, **заминусовать**, а затем **проголосовать в очереди за удаление**. Это имеет несколько преимуществ:

- пост гарантированно будет отмечен как спам;
- пост получит минимум две оценки −1.

Это заметно ускорит автоматическое уничтожение аккаунта автора поста.

Впрочем, это всё опционально. Даже если все спамерские посты будут удаляться через VLQ, то, во-первых, автор рано или поздно будет забанен (удалённые посты отрицательно сказываются на карме), во-вторых, посты будут удалены достаточно оперативно, то есть спам будет неэффективен, и только самые упёртые спамеры выживут.

Comment: `заметно ускорит автоматическое уничтожение аккаунта автора поста` - оказывается, аккаунты не удаляются. Но спам удаляется и блокируется на пару дней IP.

Answer (score 1):

В очереди VLQ нет кнопки тревоги (как нет и up/down vote). Вот пользователи и жмут "Удалить" выбирая то, что кажется подходящим вариантом.

Лично я сначала жму "Удалить" без комментов, и если спам остался жив - открываю и добиваю флагом. Потому что это проще и удобнее.

Comment: Я обычно в таких случаях открываю вопрос в новом окне и голосую/включаю тревогу.

Comment: @VladD: простое и изящное решение :) Вообще, спам даже попадать в эту очередь не должен (разве что система сама забросила, т.к. короткий).

Comment: @VladD все так делают.

Comment: @Vlad вот только гораздо проще сначала ткнуть "удалить", а потом уже пойти по ссылке и поставить флаг, если обычного "удалить" не хватило.

Comment: @VladD вот, например - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470739/177221 - какой смысл был ждать еще 3-4 тревоги "спам", если была возможность снести его в один клик

Comment: @PashaPash: Идея модерации сообщества в том, что она ненапряжна. Ткнули в тревогу и пошли дальше, не заботясь о том, через 5 или 10 минут вопрос исчезнет.

Comment: @VladD да, но при просмотре очереди VLQ, кнопка "удалить" есть. а кнопки "тревога" - нет. Гораздо проще ткнуть "удалить" и пойти мимо не поставив тревогу.

Comment: @PashaPash: Как бы да. Но это тогда скорее предложение на en.Meta

Comment: Я ничуть не возражаю против того, что вы удаляете ответ самостоятельно, если «спам» тоже нажмете. Автор должен получать заслуженные тревоги в карму или что там вместо нее.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот только если ответ удален - на уже него нельзя поставить тревогу

Comment: @PashaPash можно для модератора, чтобы он руками забанил спамера

Comment: @PashaPash, флаг полезен хотя бы тем, что модераторы узнают о спамере.