# Сбился перевод сообщения об удаленном спаме

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.

Кажется, раньше это сообщение было переведено

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо! Действительно, изменилась строка на английском и, как результат, слетели переводы. Поправил. В ближайшее время будет на сайте.